# C# ListBox ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to use a ListBox.DataSource = ObservableCollection, however I can't figure out how to have the listbox automatically update when my OC updates. I can hook the CollectionChanged event on the OC, however what do I need to do to the listbox to make it update?

Comment: WinForms, but I included the WindowsBase assembly that contains ObserveableCollection. Is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: Winforms is notified by IBindingList as Justin Niessner has described below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you're trying to use `ObservableCollection<T>` in a WinForms application.

`ObservableCollection<T>` is primarily used in WPF development. In WinForms, for the control be automatically updates as the collection changes your collection needs to implement `IBindingList`.

The easiest solution is to use `BindingList<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`. After that, your controls should update as the collection changes.

[MSDN: BindingList(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Or wait for .NET 4.0 to come out; `ObservableCollection<T>` will be moved to System.dll:  http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/10/21/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-2-justin-van-patten.aspx     (see the last item)