# ListBox datasource from LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listbox, datasource

Let's say there is a `List<Person>` where `Person{Name, age, etc}`.

What I want is a ListBox with all Person's names as items.
Only detail. I want it to update automatically.

I wonder if it is possible to create a dynamic datasource that gets the names of the `List<Person>` and then the `ListBox` is binded to that datasource.

Any suggestions other than using a datasourse are welcome.
I found [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx) that is used in .net 4. Anything similar to .Net3.5?

Comment: `LinqDataSource` is availible in .net 3.5 I think

Comment: It is indeed, but not in WinForms.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [C# ListBox ObservableCollection<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097447/c-listbox-observablecollectiont).

Comment: @R0MANARMY that is really helpful but doesn't answer my question.
How can I make a dynamic BindingList?
I am not intended to change my model. I want to use the List<Person>
and somehow the Binding list should update its self from the List<Person>

Comment: `List<T>` does not have any events. You will have to use a timer or some other datastructure that has events.

Comment: When you say you want it to update automatically, you mean that the listbox should automatically show the new data when a change is done at the database level?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something "more" than this but I am not sure from your question what that is. So I am posting this code for you to further explain your goal.

```
    namespace SO_Forms_Demo
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      List<person> people;
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         List<string> dataList = new List<string>(){"Moe","Larry","Curly"};
         listBox1.DataSource = dataList;

          people = new List<person>(){new person(){name="Moe",age=44,shoeSize=9},
                                       new person(){name="Larry",age=45,shoeSize=10},
                                       new person(){name="Curly",age=46,shoeSize=11}
                                      };
          bindList2();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         person Shemp = new person() { name = "Shemp", age = 49, shoeSize = 12 };
         people.Add(Shemp);
         bindList2();
      }

      private void bindList2()
      {
         listBox2.DataSource = null;
         listBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
         listBox2.DataSource = people;
      }

   }

   public class person
   {
      public string name { get; set; }
      public int age { get; set; }
      public int shoeSize { get; set; }
   }


}
```